# I'm not able to insert an element at the end of the linked list and display it in C

Tags: c

C program for basic linked list implementation with Create, Display, count (number of nodes), insert functions

```c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct Node      // Node structure
    {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
    }Node;
    Node *first=NULL;
    
    void create(int A[],int n)    // function to create a structure
    {      
        first=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        first->data=A[0];
        first->next=NULL;
        Node *temp;
        temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
        first->next=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            temp->next=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            temp->data=A[i];
            if(i==n)
            {temp->next=NULL;
            break;
            }
            else
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    int count(Node *p)       // to count the number of nodes in the list
    {
        int count=0;
        while(p->next!=NULL)
        {
            count=count+1;
            p=p->next;
        }
        return count;
    
    }
    void Display(Node *p)       // function to display the list
    {
        
       while(p->next!=NULL)
       {
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p=p->next;
       }
    }
    
    void insert(int index, int key)       // function to insert the elements in the list
    {
        if(index<0 || index>count(first))   // to check the index 
        {
            printf("\nErr... Invalid index");
        }
    
        if(index==0)                  // if index is the first node then it the new node should be 
                                      // the first node
        {
            Node *temp=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            temp->data=key;
            temp->next=first;
            first=temp;
        }
        
        if(index==count(first))                // if new node is the last node to be inserted
        {   Node *temp=first;
            int i=1;
            //while(temp->next!=NULL)
            while(i<index)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
                i++;
            }
            Node *last=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if(temp->next ==NULL)
            printf("\n we are the last node");
            temp->next=last;
            last->data=key;
            //last->data=key;
            last->next=NULL;
            
        }
        if(index!=0 && index !=count(first))   // if the new node is not the first or the last
        {
            Node *temp=first;
            int count=1;
            while(count<index)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
                count++;
            }
            Node *last=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            last->data=key;
            last->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=last;
        }
    }
    int main()
    { 
        int A[]={1,3,5,12};
        create(A,(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])));
        insert(4,10);
        Display(first);
        return(0);
    }
```

---

```
I/p: insert(0,10)    o/p: 10 1 3 5 12 
I/p: insert(1,10)    o/p: 1 10 3 5 12 
I/p: insert(2,10)    o/p: 1 3 10 5 12 
I/p: insert(3,10)    o/p: 1 3 5 10 12 
I/p: insert(4,10)    o/p: 1 3 5 12   -----> This is the one that I'm getting stuck at I'm supposed to get 1 3 5 12 10 as the output
```

Comment: `Node *first=NULL;` <-- Don't use global-variables.

Comment: Assuming that `n` is the number of elements in the array `A`, then the loop `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` will go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Also, in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: And I really recommend that you create separate function to deal with simple list operations, like adding at head or at the tail. Then your `create` function would become much simpler. Simpler code means it's less likely to contain bug, and also become easier to debug if it contains bugs, and to maintain as well. And separate list and node handling, for example by creating a list structure which have the head (and possibly tail) pointers, and also a count (so you don't have to call `count` all the time).

Answer (score 0):

Your count is wrong, the list with only the `first` element has size 1, but your code will return 0. In `count()` start count with `int count = 1;`, because any node that is not NULL itself is always a part of a list with at least size 1.